# Excel VBA MultiPage - get number of pages

Tags: vba, excel

I created a multipage form in excel vba 2010.
How can get the number of pages in this mulitpage?

Thanks,
blackmail

Comment: Just to clarify: Do you want to get the number of pages in the FORM?

Comment: The number of pages within the multipage part which is in the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim mulpage as Control, pge as Page, counter as Integer
For Each mulPage In Me.Controls
       If TypeName(mulPage) = "MultiPage" Then
           For Each pge In mulPage.Pages
               counter = counter + 1
           Next pge
       End If
Next
```

> **[My code is in 2003. So for you, you need to reference the `Form Page property` explicitly using  `Dim pge As msforms.Page` instead of `Dim pge As Page` for 2007, 2010...going forward.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264582.aspx)**

References:

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/155374
- http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/free-training/ExcelVBA2/excelvba2lesson8.htm

Comment: Shouldn't it be `If TypeName(mulPage)= "MultiPage"`?

Comment: I followed your answer and the references, but it doesn't work for me. what do you mean in "somename", the name of the multipage?

Comment: Sorry you have to use what @Doug pointed out. It has to be the type name `MultiPage` I mixed it up as for control's `Name`..

Comment: When i try it with typename(mulpage) = "MultiPage", the inner loop, running on the page, announce of an "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch"

Comment: Are you using the correct Page property as pointed out in answer for 2007, 2010 version? `DIM PGE AS MSFORMS.PAGE`?

Comment: accepted and rewarded. how did you get into the object model changes issue?

Comment: For that see here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lv-LV/isvvba/thread/1278a2ec-b9e6-434b-8ae4-2907ddf21d70 Even in the main 2010 Excel MSDN article it shows as `msforms.Page`.

Comment: Err... excuse me guys, but, what is the problem with the code below? MultiPage1.Pages.Count

Answer (score 1):

use the following to get the number of pages in a multipage

```
msgbox Multipage1.Pages.Count
```